# Programmatically linked UIView block-based animations hang at the first time fired on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

In my project, the program fire an animation when querying the database, when it receives the response data, it fires another animation automatically to display the data.

```
-(void)queryDatabase{
    //...querying database ...
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{ 
                       //...first animation block...
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                       //...first completion block...
                     }];
}

-(void)receivedResponse:(NSData *)responseData{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{ 
                       //...second animation block...
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                       //...second completion block...
                     }];
}
```

My problem is, when the program is initiated and fire the second animation at the first time received response, the "second animation block" is exactly executed, but the "second completion block" is not executed and the screen does not change until about 20 or more seconds passed. After that, when this cycle is invoked again, the second animation will always work correctly. How to fix?

Comment: Is the received response executing on the main thread? You can put a break point on the receivedResponse method and see what thread it is being called on in the debug navigator in xcode

Comment: are you writing something in animations block, that is taking time to get executed the first time?

Comment: to Puneet: The code in animation block are all about appearance of subviews, such as hide/show, changing frames, changing alpha. No time-consuming code, and there is no difference between the first time execution and the consequent ones. It works correctly on the simulator, but lag a lot on iPhone 4S

Comment: Why don't you try placing a couple of `NSLog` in there to see if they print at the correct time and whether it is just the interface having problems?

Comment: to bandejapaisa: You are right! every time the "second animation block" hangs, it is not on the main thread! It looks like getting closer. But how to make sure to run the animation on the main thread?

Comment: @bandejapaisa Thank you!

Every time the animation hangs, it's really executing on a NSOperationQueue thread, not on the main thread. I don't know how this happen, perhaps the method receivedResponse: is called directly by the async queue thread which was querying the database by NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:, and made the animation executed outside the main thread.

I use [self performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone] instead to invoke the second animation, then the problem is solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, all UI code should execute on the main thread. You will get unexpected results if you don't abide by this. I've experienced nothing happening at all when I want some UI code to run, and apps hanging whenever I've mistakenly run UI code on a background thread. There are plenty of discussions on why UI code has to run on the main thread.

If you know you're receivedResponse method is going to execute on a thread other than the main thread, you can easily bring it back to the main thread using Grand Central Dispatch (GCD). GCD is a lot nicer to use than the performSelectorOnMainThread methods...

```
-(void)receivedResponse:(NSData *)responseData{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // put your UI code in here
    });
}
```